# How to pass whole model object to mvc4 controller?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model

I have table on view. I want to have export to excel button. I want to pass whole model object to Controller. I have tried like this:

My view:

```
@model Project.Models.Results
 ...

@Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadAction", Model)
```

And my controller:

```
public ActionResult DownloadAction(Results model){...}
```

When i try it like this, model has properties with null values.

Can anybody help me to pass model to controller?

Answer (score 1):

If you have simple model your code should work. But if you have complex model you just cant do it with `ActionLink`.

The only model that you can pass is model with simple properties like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   //etc...
}
```

Comment: it is a complex model, i have array of results. Is there any way i can do it?

Comment: @user3549602 yes, array is a complex. You should use ajax call in your case.

Comment: Could you write that code for me in jquery? I dont know how to pass model to jquery. Thank you.

Comment: @user3549602 actually it's better to ask another question for this with some more details about your model. I just don't have time for this now.

Answer (score 0):

There is few ways to pass model to the view from controller. you can use TempData, ViewData or ViewBag or you can add model to your view on top of your view

```
@model Your_Model
```

and can access the value in foreach loop

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
//your data in item.something
}
```

OR
you can pass the data to viewbag and access on view like this..

```
public ActionResult actionName()
{
ViewBag.ModelName=Result;
//Result in viewbag now
}
```

On view

```
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.ModelName)
{
    //your data in item.something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But i need to pass model i rendered on view to another action in controller?